# How can a program which forks itself repeatedly in a loop be killed?

Tags: c, kill

I made some weird experiment and created a program that forks itself and executes itself in the child process, which is forked again and executes itself again...and so on.

Only after exiting the ssh session I was connected to it stopped.
What are the possible ways to kill such program, which continuously changes it's own PID ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int spawn (char* program, char** arg_list)
{
  pid_t child_pid;


  child_pid = fork ();
  if (child_pid != 0)
    /* This is the parent process. */
    return child_pid;
  else {

    printf("my pid is %d my ppid is %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
    execvp (program,  arg_list);

    fprintf (stderr,  "an error occurred in execvp\n");
    abort ();
  }
}

int main ()
{

  char* arg_list[] = {
    "./1",     /* argv[0], the name of the program.  */
    NULL      
  };

  spawn ("./1", arg_list);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Somewhat similar to this: https://superuser.com/questions/168804/how-do-i-kill-a-forkbomb-process

Comment: You created a [Fork Bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb)

Comment: Cool, I will read about it. thanks.

Comment: I remember one of my first assignments in Operating Systems was to create a "Ping/Pong" program where a "Ping" program forked a "Pong" program and vice-versa, but only a specified number of times. Needless to say I crashed my terminal (so did my other classmates)

Comment: Restarting your computer should do the trick.